# Is leaving out the current user ID in a REST endpoint bad practice?

Tags: rest

I'm currently writing my own REST API. One of my endpoints is named `/api/profile`, which takes either `GET` to retrieve or `PUT` to update this profile. I have been told that it's considered bad practice or plain wrong to not include any form of user ID, email or username in the URL, when calling `PUT /api/profile`. Every request has a Bearer token for authentication, which makes the server load the user in case and stores it in the request data. Upon updating information using PUT, I thought it'd be safe to assume that if no parameter has been supplied to the URL, the target is `self`, in this case, the authenticated user.

Am I wrong to make this assumption and/or is this a bad example of REST?

Comment: Ruben, since you know the location of the resource, in this case a Profile, which you are getting through authentication a PUT with no id is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the architectural constraints of REST is to make your resources cacheable.

When you have some proxy or other cache between your client and server, the request line `GET /api/profile` cannot be cached, or another user would potentially retrieve the wrong profile.

You could use a `Vary: Authorization` header in your case to prevent this. But having an id in the URL will make unequivocally clear which resource you want to retrieve.

For `PUT` requests, this is not an issue as they won't be cached, but you should keep your URI design consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your input